# I'm trying to show Δ symbol on my website . but it does not reflect on the webpage

Tags: html, css, browser, symbols, graphical-logo

This is code I'm using to show my company logo, the problem is the Δ symbol does not reflect in the browser.

```
strong class="footer-logo">KyΔnsys</strong
```

I'm using unicode `charset="utf-8"`

Comment: can you show your website code ??

Comment: Which CSS rules are using, especially as regards to fonts? What do you actually see in a browser? Is your page *actually* UTF-8 encoded, are have you just got some declaration somewhere (where?) claiming that it is?

Comment: I have declared a meta tag -- meta charset="utf-8" in the head of the html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
&Delta;
```

As in KyΔnsys

Just saw the utf-8 encoding, then

```
&#916;
```

will work

Answer (score 3):

Use `&#916;` or `&Delta;`

See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6V35V/1/)

Comment: Nope this does'nt help. The delta sign does not appear in the text .

Answer (score 0):

Try now ,

```
<p>Ky&#916;nsys </p>
```